# How to install a squeak smalltalk plugin?

Tags: smalltalk, squeak

I am trying to use squeakSSL with WebClient, the squeakSSL page says:

> To install SqueakSSL you need to download and install the binary version of the plugin and then install SqueakSSL via:

```
(Installer ss)
project: 'SqueakSSL';
    install: 'SqueakSSL-Core';
    install: 'SqueakSSL-Tests';
```

I downloaded the mentioned package, and it is just a dll file.  I can't find anywhere on the net how you install a squeak plugin.  I tried putting it in the VM and Image directories, but the squeakSSL tests fail.

How do you install a squeak plugin?

Answer (score 4):

First, you have to download the DLL file and put it in your VM directory. Next, open a workspace in Squeak and run:

```
(Installer ss)
    project: 'SqueakSSL'; 
    install: 'SqueakSSL-Core'; 
    install: 'SqueakSSL-Tests'.
```

This will install the appropriate Squeak classes necessary to access to plugin. This should be everything you need to do.

If it doesn't work, try checking the output of:

```
Smalltalk listLoadedModules
```

The SSL plugin should be listed after you tried running a test. If the plugin is listed, but the tests still fail it's probable that something -- either the Smalltalk classes or the binary plugin -- is outdated.